# Lebesgue measure of proper subset

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that if A is a proper subset of B, then the Lebesgue measure of A is strictly less than the Lebesgue measure of B?

Comment: What happens to the measure of a closed interval if you remove one of its endpoints?

Comment: $A=[0,1)\subset b=[0,1]$ $m(A)=m(B)=1-0=1$ or even $m(\mathbb{R})=m(\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No,
take $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\backslash \{\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any finite subset of the real line and remove any point(s), measure always remain the same(zero).

Answer (score 1):

There exist nonempty sets of Lebesgue measure zero. Take such a set and one of its proper subsets.